# How can I convert my API response into PHP Array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I Have this data from my API Call.

> [{\"packagename\":\"Book+-+Outliers\",\"trackingnumber\":\"1Z2FF4063A00030059\",\"packageweight\":\"1.0000\",\"weightunit\":\"Lbs\",\"price\":\"16.9900\",\"suiteno\":[],\"user_id\":\"NOTFOUND\"},{\"packagename\":\"Book+-+Outliers\",\"trackingnumber\":\"1Z2FF4063A00030059\",\"packageweight\":\"1.0000\",\"weightunit\":\"Lbs\",\"price\":\"16.9900\",\"suiteno\":\"TY1000234\",\"user_id\":\"1000234\"},{\"packagename\":\"Book+-+David+%26+Goliath+%3B+Face+Cream+-+Clinique%2FGlycolix\",\"trackingnumber\":\"9.36E+21\",\"packageweight\":\"2.0000\",\"weightunit\":\"Lbs\",\"price\":\"18.0000\",\"suiteno\":\"TY1000234\",\"user_id\":\"1000234\"},{\"packagename\":\"Sunglasses+-+Valentino\",\"trackingnumber\":\"1.02E+33\",\"packageweight\":\"0.5000\",\"weightunit\":\"Lbs\",\"price\":null,\"suiteno\":\"TY1000431\",\"user_id\":\"1000431\"},{\"packagename\":\"Sunglasses+-+Safilo+group\",\"trackingnumber\":\"1.01E+33\",\"packageweight\":\"0.8000\",\"weightunit\":\"Lbs\",\"price\":null,\"suiteno\":\"TY1000431\",\"user_id\":\"1000431\"},{\"packagename\":\"Pigmentation+Color+Tobacco\",\"trackingnumber\":\"'42060106''9405510200830072094975'\",\"packageweight\":\"0.6300\",\"weightunit\":\"Lbs\",\"price\":\"320.0000\",\"suiteno\":[],\"user_id\":\"NOTFOUND\"}]

How can I convert this data into **PHP Array**? I tried using `json_decode($result,true)` but it is not working properly. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

My PHP Code

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $json_result = json_decode(stripslashes($result), true);
    $json=str_replace("\\",'', $result);
    $jsondata=json_decode($json,true);

    print_r($jsondata);
    //echo $result;
```

Comment: use decode, not encode

Comment: Hi. Sorry I was using decode already and not encode. It was a typo.

Comment: How about you tell us what "not working properly" means? Also, care to provide the minimal example that you probably have heard of already?

Comment: I do this and I print the array using pre and print_r but the result is not displayed as an array. Just as a string.

Comment: i put your data into a string and called `json_decode` on it. everything worked, did not find any problem - *could not reproduce*. can you please include the code *how* you retreive the data from your API?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Please check my updated question.

Comment: @AliZia in your first commented line, *why exactly* did you add single quotes in the beginning and end? try it without them

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Currently I have commented the codes.

Comment: @AliZia yeah. i can see that. that's why i said "the first commented line". just try a `json_decode(strip_slashes($result), true);` and then print **json_result**

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I updated my code and I get blank screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `json_decode()` for this:

```
// It will convert the given json to an array
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
// The second param is for array, o/w it will return an object
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Hi. Sorry I was using decode already and not encode. It was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $json='[{\"packagename\":\"Book+-+Outliers\",\"trackingnumber\":\"1Z2FF4063A00030059\",\"packageweight\":\"1.0000\",\"weightunit\":\"Lbs\",\"price\":\"16.9900\",\"suiteno\":[],\"user_id\":\"NOTFOUND\"},{\"packagename\":\"Book+-+Outliers\",\"trackingnumber\":\"1Z2FF4063A00030059\",\"packageweight\":\"1.0000\",\"weightunit\":\"Lbs\",\"price\":\"16.9900\",\"suiteno\":\"TY1000234\",\"user_id\":\"1000234\"},{\"packagename\":\"Book+-+David+%26+Goliath+%3B+Face+Cream+-+Clinique%2FGlycolix\",\"trackingnumber\":\"9.36E+21\",\"packageweight\":\"2.0000\",\"weightunit\":\"Lbs\",\"price\":\"18.0000\",\"suiteno\":\"TY1000234\",\"user_id\":\"1000234\"},{\"packagename\":\"Sunglasses+-+Valentino\",\"trackingnumber\":\"1.02E+33\",\"packageweight\":\"0.5000\",\"weightunit\":\"Lbs\",\"price\":null,\"suiteno\":\"TY1000431\",\"user_id\":\"1000431\"},{\"packagename\":\"Sunglasses+-+Safilo+group\",\"trackingnumber\":\"1.01E+33\",\"packageweight\":\"0.8000\",\"weightunit\":\"Lbs\",\"price\":null,\"suiteno\":\"TY1000431\",\"user_id\":\"1000431\"},{\"packagename\":\"Pigmentation+Color+Tobacco\",\"trackingnumber\":\"420601069405510200830072094975\",\"packageweight\":\"0.6300\",\"weightunit\":\"Lbs\",\"price\":\"320.0000\",\"suiteno\":[],\"user_id\":\"NOTFOUND\"}]';

$json=str_replace("\\",'', $json);
$jsondata=json_decode($json,true);

  print_r($jsondata);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$jsonData = stripslashes(html_entity_decode($result));     
$output = json_decode($jsonData, true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
echo "</pre>";
```

Or Try this way,

```
$out = preg_replace('/\\\"/',"\"", $result);
$output = json_decode($out, true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: displays nothing.

Answer (score 0):

CURL output is json and in line $json_result = json_decode($result, true); you decoded it to an array, after str_replace you have an array but you decoded it again, may be if you remove $jsondata=json_decode($json,true); and return $json you receive an array

Answer (score 0):

Your string `\"trackingnumber\":\"'42060106''9405510200830072094975'\"` has syntax error.

```
$result = '[{\"packagename\":\"Book+-+Outliers\",\"trackingnumber\":\"1Z2FF4063A00030059\",\"packageweight\":\"1.0000\",\"weightunit\":\"Lbs\",\"price\":\"16.9900\",\"suiteno\":[],\"user_id\":\"NOTFOUND\"},{\"packagename\":\"Book+-+Outliers\",\"trackingnumber\":\"1Z2FF4063A00030059\",\"packageweight\":\"1.0000\",\"weightunit\":\"Lbs\",\"price\":\"16.9900\",\"suiteno\":\"TY1000234\",\"user_id\":\"1000234\"},{\"packagename\":\"Book+-+David+%26+Goliath+%3B+Face+Cream+-+Clinique%2FGlycolix\",\"trackingnumber\":\"9.36E+21\",\"packageweight\":\"2.0000\",\"weightunit\":\"Lbs\",\"price\":\"18.0000\",\"suiteno\":\"TY1000234\",\"user_id\":\"1000234\"},{\"packagename\":\"Sunglasses+-+Valentino\",\"trackingnumber\":\"1.02E+33\",\"packageweight\":\"0.5000\",\"weightunit\":\"Lbs\",\"price\":null,\"suiteno\":\"TY1000431\",\"user_id\":\"1000431\"},{\"packagename\":\"Sunglasses+-+Safilo+group\",\"trackingnumber\":\"1.01E+33\",\"packageweight\":\"0.8000\",\"weightunit\":\"Lbs\",\"price\":null,\"suiteno\":\"TY1000431\",\"user_id\":\"1000431\"},{\"packagename\":\"Pigmentation+Color+Tobacco\",\"trackingnumber\":\"420601069405510200830072094975\",\"packageweight\":\"0.6300\",\"weightunit\":\"Lbs\",\"price\":\"320.0000\",\"suiteno\":[],\"user_id\":\"NOTFOUND\"}]';

$json_result = json_decode(stripslashes($result), true);
$json=str_replace("\\",'', $result);
$jsondata=json_decode($json,true);

print_r($jsondata);
```